# Apache Airflow with Google OAuth logins, how?

Tags: airflow, google-oauth

we would like to use google workspace to authenticate against apache airflow. i have set up an oauth client as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server?hl=en), downloaded the docker-compose airflow setup from [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html), and then tried to configure airflow as described - mostly - [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/security/webserver.html#example-using-team-based-authorization-with-github-oauth).

when i then click on the "login using google" button, i get to the consent screen, i can accept, and i'm being redirected to my test-server "localhost:8080". (docker setup).

**it then tells me "invalid login".**

some observations:

- i have not configured a security manager, as i don't know how and what for
- it seems the redirect url is correct
  (which is `.../oauth-authorized/google`, actually),
  as before i did *not* have it configured correctly, and google didn't even
  perform the login
- i have not configured an "authentication backend",
  as i only found this in older versions of airflow
- the docker image (apache/airflow, v2.5.1) has library `oauthlib 3.2.2` installed
- when i test the OIDC flow with [oauthdebugger](https://oauthdebugger.com), google issues a token for me. **so i think the "problem" is somewhere on the airflow side**

this is my `webserver_config.py`:

```py
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
import os

# OAUTH configuration for Airflow Web Server

# copied from default config
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
WTF_CSRF_TIME_LIMIT = None

# oauth specific
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
AUTH_ROLES_SYNC_AT_LOGIN = True  # Checks roles on every login
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = False
# FAB_SECURITY_MANAGER_CLASS = "your_module.your_security_manager_class"

OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
        "name": "google",
        "token_key": "access_token",
        "icon": "fa-google",
        "remote_app": {
            "api_base_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/",
            "client_kwargs": {"scope": "email profile"},
            "access_token_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            "authorize_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "request_token_url": None,
            "client_id": "123456789012-asdfkjhagsdfkjhgasdkfjhgasdfkjhgapps.googleusercontent.com",
            "client_secret": "wooooo",
        },
    }
]
```

here is the relevant `docker-compose.yaml` part:

```yaml
  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    # ... rest is unchanged ... 
    volumes:
      - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-./data/airflow}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-./data/airflow}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
      - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-./data/airflow}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
      - ./webserver_config.py:/opt/airflow/webserver_config.py
```

funny thing is, it apparently seems to load files for web pages when coming back to airflow, but i can't leave the login screen and no matter what i do, i get the popup message "Invalid login. Please try again."

as i am fairly stuck i'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the proper redirect_url that you've set as `Authorized redirect URIs` in `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient`?

```
'remote_app': {
    'api_base_url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/',
    'client_kwargs': {'scope': 'email profile'},
    'access_token_url': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    'authorize_url': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    'request_token_url': None,
    'client_id': os.getenv("OAUTH_APP_ID"),
    'client_secret': os.getenv("OAUTH_APP_SECRET"),
    'redirect_url': '/oauth-authorized/google',
},
```

Comment: not sure, will try again. now everybody hass passwords, which is horribly annoying, but works so far. will re-visit next week, thanks!